# Are there any prophecies about self proclaimed God-men of Kali Yuga in scriptures?

Tags: puranas, kali-yuga

In the name of God many people nowadays portrait themselves as God-men. People without realizing the true nature are going and getting cheated .

Is there any mythological evidence that God-men will be more in  commencement of Kaliyuga?. If I am correct, 5003 years are completed in  4,32,000 years of Kaliyuga period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar type of prediction is present in Srimad Bhagvatam.

One is for those type of so called scholars / God Head person who argue by juggling words or misinterpreting scriptures:

Srimad Bhagvatam 12.2.4

> लिङ्गम् एवाश्रम-ख्याताव् अन्योन्यापत्ति-कारणम्। 
>   अवृत्त्या न्याय-दौर्बल्यं पाण्डित्ये चापलं वचः।। 
>  
>   A person’s spiritual position will be ascertained merely according to external symbols, and on that same basis people will change from one spiritual order to the next. A person’s propriety will be seriously questioned if he dos not earn a good living. And one **who is very clever at juggling words will be considered a learned scholar.**

Another is for those so called God-Head / Priest who run after food, wealth and lust:

Srimad Bhagvatam 12.3.32:

> दस्यूत्कृष्टा जनपदा वेदाः पाषण्ड-दूषिताः। 
>   राजानश् च प्रजा-भक्षा शिश्नोदर-परा द्विजाः।। 
>  
>   Cities will be dominated by thieves, the Vedas will be contaminated by speculative interpretations of atheists, political leaders will virtually consume the citizens, and the **so-called priests** and intellectuals **will be devotees of their bellies and genitals.**

Comment: @Tezz--further a little bit explanation. 50% of the answer is completed.